# resizing in Paintcomponent

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics

so i have a program where i display an image using paintComponent (arcs and ovals, to be precise) beside a set of JButtons and a JTextArea, and i want the arcs/ovals to change size when/if the user changes the size of the frame. i have implemented the getWidth, getHeight stuff, but i cant seem to get it to work.

this is my code. if i dont setPreferredSize, then it doesnt work; the arcs/ovals get squished between the edge of the frame and the buttons. if i try to use getWidth() and getHeight() instead of 200 for size, it doesnt work either; the arcs/ovals dont show up at all. not sure what to do.

also, any tips on making my code less convoluted (eg. if only need one class) would be appreciated.

```
public class GUIDesign
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GUIFrame frame = new GUIFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
class GUIFrame extends JFrame
{
PaintPanel2 canvas = new PaintPanel2();
public GUIFrame()
{
    ...

    add(mainHolder, BorderLayout.CENTER);   //has the JButtons, JTextArea.
    add(canvas, BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.setTitle("this");
    this.pack();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
}
class PaintPanel2 extends JPanel
{
private static int SIZE = 200;

public PaintPanel2()
{
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE));
}
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    int xCenter = getWidth()/2;
    int yCenter = getHeight()/2;

    int startOvalX = (int) (xCenter/5);
    int startOvalY = (int) (yCenter/5);
    int endOvalX = (int) (xCenter * 1.5);
    int endOvalY = (int) (yCenter * 1.5);
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillArc(startOvalX, startOvalY, endOvalX, endOvalY, 0, 180);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawArc(startOvalX, startOvalY, endOvalX, endOvalY, 0, 180);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillOval((int)(startOvalX/1.5) - 1, (int) (startOvalY * 2.5),(int) (endOvalX * 1.1) + 2,(int)(endOvalY/1.5));
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillOval((int)(startOvalX/1.5), (int) (startOvalY * 2.5) -1,(int) (endOvalX * 1.1),(int)(endOvalY/1.5));
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using a `BorderLayout` as the layout manager, the component that is added in the `CENTER` will be the one to resize when the main container resizes. So, if you change the code to have the canvas in the center, you will get the expected results:

```
add(mainHolder, BorderLayout.WEST);   //has the JButtons, JTextArea.
add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```